# XSLT: run for-each body only once for multiple satisfied if conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and I have to make some changes in an existing XSLT file.

I have the following sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Item>
  <SubItems>
    <SubItem>
      <InnerItem>
        <ValueToSearch>XYZ</ValueToSearch>
        <Level>0</Level>
        <InnerItem>
          <ValueToSearch>Value1</ValueToSearch>
          <Level>1</Level>
          <InnerItem>
            <ValueToSearch>ABC</ValueToSearch>
            <Level>2</Level>
            <InnerItem>
              <ValueToSearch>Value2</ValueToSearch>
              <Level>3</Level>
            </InnerItem>
          </InnerItem>
        </InnerItem>
      </InnerItem>
      <InnerItem>
        <ValueToSearch>IJK</ValueToSearch>
        <Level>0</Level>
      </InnerItem>
      <InnerItem>
        <ValueToSearch>Value3</ValueToSearch>
        <Level>0</Level>
        <InnerItem>
          <ValueToSearch>HYT</ValueToSearch>
          <Level>1</Level>
        </InnerItem>
      </InnerItem>
    </SubItem>
  </SubItems>
</Item>
```

In the above XML, I want to loop through all `<InnerItem>` tags (including the nested one's) and read the value `<ValueToSearch>` tag value and check if it is present in a variable with multiple space separated values. My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:variable name="List" select="'Value1 Value2 Value3'"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Item/SubItems/SubItem">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//InnerItem[contains( concat(' ', $List, ' '), concat(' ', ValueToSearch , ' '))]">
            <Value>
              <xsl:value-of select="ValueToSearch"/>
            </Value>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the above XSLT, all the `<InnerItem>` tags (including the nested one's) are looped through and value of `<ValueToSearch>` search tag is checked if it is present in the `$List` variable which is working fine.

My problem here is since there are two matching values present in the `<ValueToSearch>` tags, the body of the `for-each` tag runs two times. If there are more matching values in the XML for `<ValueToSearch>` tags, the body of the loop runs that many number of times.

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ValueToSearch>Value1</ValueToSearch>
<ValueToSearch>Value2</ValueToSearch>
<ValueToSearch>Value3</ValueToSearch>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ValueToSearch>Value1</ValueToSearch>
```

My requirement is that if the matching value is found, just run the the body of the `for-each` tag only once by adding another `xsl:if` which will satisfy only once for all matching values. I understand there is not way to break the loop in XSLT but is there a simpler way to achiever what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the output you actually expect here? At the moment, the `xsl:for-each` will return all `InnerItem` nodes that match the list, but it sounds like this is not what you want. Thanks.

Comment: @TimC edited the question with current and expected outputs

Comment: Does your actual XML contain multiple `SubItem` elements? If so, do you want to return the first value within each `SubItem`, or the first value in the document as a whole?

Comment: @TimC yes actually, I missed that part in the question as I was creating sample XML data from my acutal data, I want to check first matching value as a whole and not for each `<SubItem>`, check: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you simply want to process only

```
<xsl:for-each select="(.//InnerItem[contains( concat(' ', $List, ' '), concat(' ', ValueToSearch , ' '))])[1]">
```

that is, the first `InnerItem` for which your condition holds.

Also it seems you want only one `for-each`, not two nested ones, so

```
<xsl:for-each select="(//InnerItem[contains( concat(' ', $List, ' '), concat(' ', ValueToSearch , ' '))])[1]">
        <Value>
          <xsl:value-of select="ValueToSearch"/>
        </Value>
</xsl:for-each>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhk/1

Comment: This is not working, still getting all items. I am using `MSXSL` as the `XSLT` processor, maybe there is different way to get the only the first item from the `for-each` loop for `MSXSL`? EDIT: just checked the `position()` and it comes as `1` for all values.

Comment: At http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbg I get only one item as the output with my suggestion.

Comment: There are multiple `<SubItem>` tags in my actual data which is returning multiple values, missed this part, sorry. Check: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhk

Comment: @seadrag0n, then you need to remove the nested for-eachs and use a single one.